# Unable to Resolve Module in React Native App for linked library

Tags: react-native

I have a problem **"Unable to resolve module"**.

// *Please, read the question before publish comments with links for first result from google.*

This is the import line where I got the error:

```
import Interactor from 'react-native-native-orientation-interactor';
```

What I did:

1. Create a react-native library
2. Run `npm link` inside the library folder
3. Run `npm link react-native-native-orientation-interactor` inside a demo react-native app
4. Add import statement
5. Got the error with import.

If I press Cmd+B on import statement I can open a file from node_modules folder. Also I can see my library (as a link) inside node_modules.

But I didn't find any solution for me.

**Upd1:** I added my library as a dependency in package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.61.5",
    "react-native-native-orientation-interactor": "*"
  },
```

Comment: are you using expo?

Comment: @Artem Is the issue resolved? I am also trying to add my library which is saved locally on my system and getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

1 - First of all you have written double native in react-native-native-orientation-interaction

2 - Another thing is, don't add dependencies manually.. 
Use Proper installation guide like

npm install --save react-native-orientation-interactor
or
yarn add react-native-orientation-interactor

then link the dependency.

3 - And actually I didn't get any module named 'react-native-orientation-interaction'.

[react-native-orientation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-orientation)

here is the one of valid module dependency.
always read the whole proper Documentation.( Correct me if I am wrong)

Comment: Hi, thank for your answer, really there is double-native) my mistake, but the library and demo app are local projects and I'm not publish the library into npm yet. So I can't to install the dependency by npm install

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to link your package correctly, and problem still persists.

```
From my experience you can do two things to resolve error.
1) Try to install pod in ios/ directory
or
2) Just close the Termianl and re-run
```